# Using enhanced for loop with lower bounded wildcard

Tags: java, generics, for-loop

I have this for loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
    System.out.print(list.get(j) + " ");
}
```

the signature of the method is:

```
public static void addNumbers(List<? super Number> anoList)
```

the list is declared as:

```
static List<? super Number> list2;
```

or

```
static List list2;
```

for that matter.

All good so far. But then Netbeans gives a hint to convert the for loop to an enhanced for loop. When i apply that i get:

```
    for (? super Number anoList1 : anoList) {
        System.out.print(anoList1 + " ");
    }
```

which is not working and produces lots of errors. For one: `cannot find anoList1` and `. expected` , `: expected` , `; expected`.

I have tried several things to get rid of the errors, but none of them is working.

What is the correct way for this `enhanced for loop` to be written?

From other topics i have read, the advice is not to use an `enhanced for loop` at all and leave it like it is.

Comment: Use `Object` instead of `? super Number` in your loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the correct way for this enhanced for loop to be written?

```
for (Object obj : anyList) {...}
```

Since a `List<? super Number>` is a List of elements which could be any supertype of `Number` (including `Object`), the only guarantee we have about the actual type of the List is `Object`.

Comment: This is working. After done so Netbeans suggest to turn that into a functional operation:  `list.stream().forEach((list1) -> {...};
        });` :) Good call. I was confused why netbeans added the lower wildboundcard without the diamond operators.

Comment: @WonderWorld, seems like a NetBeans bug. Report it.

Answer (score 3):

Here `? super Number` means that the list may contain elements of any type which is supertype of `Number`. Practically this means that nothing can be guaranteed about the list elements type except that they are descendants of `Object` type. Such method signature actually look useless. Probably you wanted to use

```
public static void addNumbers(List<? extends Number> anoList)
```

Which would mean that list element type is some *subtype* of `Number` like `List<Integer>` or `List<Double>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm riding on the answer given by Tagir.  You'll see that this won't compile

```
public static void addNumbers(List<? super Number> anoList){
    for(Number n : anoList){ // Fail

    }
}
```

Fails with

```
Error:(29, 24) java: incompatible types: capture#1 of ? super java.lang.Number cannot be converted to java.lang.Number
```

But this is good

```
public static void addNumbers(List<? extends Number> anoList){
    for(Number n : anoList){

    }
}
```

So as Tagir mentioned, you probably want to use `extends` instead of `super`.  However, if you really do need `? super Number`, then Radiodef's answer is your only option for the enhanced `for` loop.

Comment: The thing is that it is from the java tutorials `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html` and Netbeans suggests to convert it to that enhanced for loop that is not correct.

Comment: That applies to adding items to the list.  You are getting them from the list.  You should restrict the type to the abstraction necessary to perform the operation.  Again, if you *must* have it as `? super Number`, then you use Radiodef's answer.